# Turn list of tibbles into list of vectors

Tags: r, list

How can I turn a list of tibbles (all one col only) into a list of vectors?
The names of the list objects should stay the same and the col_name of the tibble should be omitted. Thanks for your help dear noble coders!

## Example

```
a_tibble <- tibble(id = c('AB', 'DRR', 'FH', 'yyb'))
another_tibble <- tibble(id = c('AB', 'DXF', 'FH', 'DKH'))

list <- list(
  list1 = a_tibble,
  list2 = another_tibble,
  list3 = a_tibble,
  list4 = another_tibble)
```

## expected result

```
result <- list(
  list1 = (c('AB', 'DRR', 'FH', 'yyb')),
  list2 = (c('AB', 'DXF', 'FH', 'DKH')),
  list3 = (c('AB', 'DRR', 'FH', 'yyb')),
  list4 = (c('AB', 'DXF', 'FH', 'DKH'))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may `unlist` each `list` -

```
lapply(list, unlist, use.names = FALSE)

#$list1
#[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

#$list2
#[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"

#$list3
#[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

#$list4
#[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
```

Answer (score 3):

A vectorized answer is:

```r
unlist(list, recursive = FALSE)

# $list1.id
# [1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"
# 
# $list2.id
# [1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
# 
# $list3.id
# [1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"
# 
# $list4.id
# [1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
```

To remove the `.id` you can do:

```r
gsub(".id", "", names(new_list), fixed = TRUE)
```

---

Microbenchmark:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  "lapply-unlist" = lapply(list, unlist, use.names = FALSE),
  "lapply-t" = lapply(list, \(i) c(t(i))),
  "unlist-rec" = unlist(list, recursive = FALSE),
  "lapply-pull" = lapply(list, dplyr::pull),
  "lapply-[[" = lapply(list, "[[", 1)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#  lapply-unlist   12.8   18.85   27.027   25.35   32.45  114.1   100
#       lapply-t  334.9  381.45  566.098  489.30  564.85 4213.3   100
#     unlist-rec    3.2    6.60   11.440   11.20   14.95   29.4   100
#    lapply-pull 1894.1 2170.80 2772.973 2580.15 3233.10 4976.2   100
#      lapply-[[   36.3   49.50   69.882   64.60   84.55  202.3   100
```

Comment: I just came to add this one to my answer. This should be the accepted one :)

Comment: I think OP does however want that the " col_name of the tibble should be omitted" which is not the case in Mael's answer unfortunately..

Comment: Indeed, the accepted one is the easiest and was the quickest, but very cool to see the engagement. Thank you all!

Comment: If you really want to benchmark the answers 1) Increase the size of the `list`. 2) `gsub` code in your answer should also be included in the benchmark since it is what gives the expected output. Only including `unlist(list, recursive = FALSE)` in benchmark is not correct imho.

Comment: Yeah, don't popularize benchmarks on data so small as to be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose and concatenate, i.e.

```
lapply(list, \(i)c(t(i)))
# or lapply(list, unlist) if you don't mind named vectors


$list1
[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

$list2
[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"

$list3
[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

$list4
[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pull`:

```
lapply(list, dplyr::pull)

$list1
[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

$list2
[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"

$list3
[1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"

$list4
[1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
```

Comment: I always appreciate a dplyr solution, but why not use map then? :)

Comment: `purrr::map(list, dplyr::pull)` - I wanted to save you to load an extra package ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(list, "[[", 1)
# $list1
# [1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"
# 
# $list2
# [1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
# 
# $list3
# [1] "AB"  "DRR" "FH"  "yyb"
# 
# $list4
# [1] "AB"  "DXF" "FH"  "DKH"
```